# How do I fix a Ruby on Rails argument error related to bootstrap-sass gem stylesheet assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have a Ruby on Rails web app based on Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial.  This past week I tried to get a production setup running on a server I own.  The current setup includes Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS, RVM, Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.8, Apache2, MySQL, & Passenger.

I was able to get the app on the web, but it has an error.  The Ubuntu machine displays the error in the browser (included below).  The error however doesn't exist on my Windows 7 development machine unless I precompile my assets.  My stylesheet assets based on the twitter bootstrap-sass gem seem to be the culprit.  If I delete the contents of custom.css.scss the application loads without errors, but obviously has no styling.  If I only include the @import "bootstrap"; statement in the custom.css.scss file it still has the error.  I also tried the gem bootstrap-rails and had the same error.  Let me know if you need more information to answer the question.  Thanks!

Showing /home/cdysert/railsprojects/testapp/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

> wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)
>     (in /home/cdysert/railsprojects/testapp/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)

Extracted source (around line #5):

```
2: <html>
3:   <head>
4:     <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
5:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
6:     <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8:     <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
```

custom.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";

/* mixins, variables, etc. */

$grayMediumLight: #eaeaea;

@mixin box_sizing {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* universal */

html {
overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
padding-top: 60px;
}

section {
overflow: auto;
}

textarea {
resize: vertical;
}

.center {
text-align: center;
h1 {
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
}

/* typography */

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
line-height: 1;
}

h1 {
font-size: 3em;
letter-spacing: -2px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
text-align: center;
}

h2 {
font-size: 1.7em;
letter-spacing: -1px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: normal;
color: $grayLight;
}

p {
font-size: 1.1em;
line-height: 1.7em;
}

/* forms */

input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
border: 1px solid #bbb;
width: 100%;
padding: 10px;
height: auto;
margin-bottom: 15px;
@include box_sizing;
}

#error_explanation {
color: #f00;
ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0 0 18px 0;
}
}

.field_with_errors {
@extend .control-group;
@extend .error;
}

/* header */

#logo {
float: left;
margin-right: 10px;
font-size: 1.7em;
color: white;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: -1px;
padding-top: 9px;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 1;
&:hover {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
}

/* footer */

footer {
margin-top: 45px;
padding-top: 5px;
border-top: 1px solid $grayMediumLight;
color: $grayLight;
a {
color: $gray;
&:hover { 
color: $grayDarker;
}
}  
small { 
float: left; 
}
ul {
float: right;
list-style: none;
li {
float: left;
margin-left: 10px;
}
}
}

/* sidebar */

aside {
section {
padding: 10px 0;
border-top: 1px solid $grayLighter;
&:first-child {
border: 0;
padding-top: 0;
}
span {
display: block;
margin-bottom: 3px;
line-height: 1;
}
h1 {
font-size: 1.6em;
text-align: left;
letter-spacing: -1px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
}
}
}

.gravatar {
float: left;
margin-right: 10px;
}

.stats {
overflow: auto;
a {
float: left;
padding: 0 10px;
border-left: 1px solid $grayLighter;
color: gray;
&:first-child {
padding-left: 0;
border: 0;
}
&:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: $blue;
}
}
strong {
display: block;
}
}

.user_avatars {
overflow: auto;
margin-top: 10px;
.gravatar {
margin: 1px 1px;
}
}


/* users index */

.users {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
li {
overflow: auto;
padding: 10px 0;
border-top: 1px solid $grayLighter;
&:last-child {
border-bottom: 1px solid $grayLighter;
}
}
}

/* microposts */

.microposts {
list-style: none;
margin: 10px 0 0 0;

li {
padding: 10px 0;
border-top: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}
}
.content {
display: block;
}
.timestamp {
color: $grayLight;
}
.gravatar {
float: left;
margin-right: 10px;
}
aside {
textarea {
height: 100px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
}

/* miscellaneous */

.debug_dump {
clear: both;
float: left;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 45px;
@include box_sizing;
}
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.4'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.11'
gem 'vincenty', '1.0.3'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
  gem 'therubyracer', '0.10.2'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end
```

Comment: That error message suggests the problem is in `/home/cdysert/railsprojects/testapp/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss`, can you show that?

Comment: @EddMorgan I have included the custom.css.scss file above.  If i remove everything from the file except the import bootstrap statement it still has the error.

Comment: It would help to see your Gemfile so we know which twitter bootstrap gem you're using and any other asset gems that might be included.

Comment: @rossta I have included the Gemfile for you.  Thanks!